# Update the target coordinates while transitioning

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am making a game in corona and I am facing a problem. I have a circle on screen and I want it to follow the touch coordinates continuously. I am using transition.to function to do so but the thing is, whenever this function get a coordinate, it completes the transition even if the coordinates are updated during the transition.

```
if event.phase == "began" or event.phase == "moved" then
    follow = true
    touchX = event.x; touchY = event.y
elseif event.phase == "ended" then
    follow = false
end
```

And in another function, I am doing this

```
if follow == true then
    transition.to(circle, {time = 500, x = touchX, y = touchY, transition = easing.inOutQuad})
end
```

The code works fine for simple touch but I want the circle to follow the touch even when it's moving.

Comment: are you trying to drag the object or you want to the object to follow your touch?

Comment: I tried your code but that is dragging the object which is not what I am trying to achieve. I want the object to follow the touch.

Comment: okay i just remove it because it's only dragging can you explain further how will you call the transition and how will it end because it's unclear to me ?

Comment: I am calling the transition function again and again using timer so that whenever the values of touchX and touchY change, transition will occur. And I am using runtime listener for touch events.

Comment: well created a code with the same concept as your's the transition occurs only when touchX and touchY got the last value and it will not follow certain point when moving because it needs to follow the value coming from the last touchX and touchY and i can't even do circular motion since i'm using transition

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the time value of a transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026578/modify-the-time-value-of-a-transition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some examples which may solve your problem.

Refer:

1) [Flight Path](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/flight-path) posted by carlos in corona Community.

2) [Move Object through a path](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/move-object-through-path) by renvis

---

Sample:

```
local circle = display.newCircle(10,10,20)
circle.x = 160
circle.y = 160

local olderTransition
local function moveCircle(e)
  if olderTransition ~= nil then
    transition.cancel( olderTransition )
  end
  olderTransition = transition.to(circle,{time=100,x=e.x,y=e.y})
end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch",moveCircle)
```

Keep Coding.......... :)

Comment: Thanks but I am not trying to make the circle follow the path. I just want it follow the touch point in a straight line and if I move the touch, the previous straight path should be cancelled and the new point should be approached.

Comment: I am adding some code to my post. See whether it is useful. It is something similar to that of 'Doğancan Arabacı's' post.

Comment: It worked! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks man! :) The thing that I was doing wrong was doing the transition in another function. Thanks to Doğancan Arabacı aswell :)

Answer (score 1):

You cant add a new transition to an object, which already in a transition. Thats why you should cancel the older transition first. You can try :

```
local olderTransition -- This should be visible outside of your function
local function blabla()
    if follow == true then
        if olderTransition ~= nil then
            transition.cancel( olderTransition )
        end
        olderTransition = transition.to(circle, {time = 500, x = touchX, y = touchY, transition = easing.inOutQuad, onComplete = function() olderTransition = nil end })
    end
end
```

Btw If you want to drag and drop objects, transitions are bad in performance way

Comment: Thanks, it works but when I move the touch, it doesn't follow it

Comment: You need to share more code block for that. I need to see your all touch function and I guess you have a event listener ( enterframe ).